# How can I bake multiple images (textures) into one image texture? EEVEE

Tags: texture-baking

Using the MixRGB node, I mixed two images and its factor is another black and white image. I will mix some other images.

I would like to back all these images into one image. How can I do this with EEVEE?

My baking process is simple, it doesn't have emission or other properties that are hard to bake. I also added the images to a plane (terrain) which is not a complex mesh. It is like adding some images together using photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EEVEE currently doesn't support baking, so you would have to use Cycles instead.

Heres how:

- Let's start with this simple hybrid texture

[image: Shading Workspace]

- Add a new image texture node, click  <kbd>+ New</kbd>  and give it an appropriate name and dimension.

[image: Shader Nodes][image: New Image Panel]

- Select this new node and find Bake Panel under Render Properties. If you cannot find it make sure you are using cycles.

[image: Render Properties]

- Let's use the Combined Bake Type. Learn about them [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/baking.html). Click  <kbd>Bake</kbd>  and wait for it to finish

[image: Bake Panel]

[image: Texture Bake Progress]

- Connect the Baked Image node into the PRincipled BSDF Node. Its a bit dark since we did not have any lights in our scene. You can even export this baked texture.

[image: Bake result]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I choose Diffuse instead of Combined. Then, I unselect Direct and Indirect. Then, I select Color. This way the image won't be darker.

Comment: @user2824371 Great! With your settings, you can drop the sample count down to 1 for super quick bake !!

Comment: Thank you again for your useful info. You're wonderful :)